# How to manage global state in NEXTJS 13, like we use redux with simple react

Tags: next.js, react-redux, redux-toolkit, next.js13

Is it a good idea to use redux/ react context to manage the global state in next13 /app dir?

Or is there any better ways to manage these states?

let's say I want to store a state for dark mode throughout the application.

I am currently thinking of using "Local storage - to store user preference"

Comment: It depends on your needs. I should advise not using redux in nextjs 13 app as it is very complex to get it working. Here’s a great article about this: [Should I use Redux in Nextjs13 app?](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/should-you-use-redux-in-next-js-5e57201c34da?gi=6967ba900645)

Comment: @leandronn, is there a way to make a global state like for IsUserAuthenticated without making the layout (or root Parent) a client component ? because de variable IsUserAuthenticated must be global for the app, so must be in root parent, so we need to make this parent as ClientComponent => all the app would be Client.

Comment: You can create a react context and use it from your layout without the need to make it a client component.